# ORA-01847 when inserting TO_DATE with oci_execute

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to insert a user entered date, which comes as a POST variable, in a DATE field and continuously getting ORA-01847. Here is what I have so far,

```
    $name = strtoupper(trim($_POST['name']));
    $dob = date('d-M-y', strtotime($_POST['dob']));
    $query = "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TABID, TABNAME, DOB, CREATEDBY) VALUES (SEQ_TAB_TABID.NEXTVAL, :1, TO_DATE(:2, 'DD-MM-YY'), :3)";
    $ins = array($name, $dob, $_SESSION['usrid']);
    $conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $constr);
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($ins as $i) {
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, sprintf(':%d', $count), $i);
        $count++;
    }
    $exec = oci_execute($stid);
```

The user input that I am getting is in the format 08/29/2015 ($_POST['dob'])

I keep getting ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

I have tried printing the final dob and it prints out 29-AUG-2015. When I use the same query and insert using SQL Developer it works perfectly.

I have even tried the "non-bind" version of the query as follows:

```
    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TABID, TABNAME, DOB, CREATEDBY) VALUES (SEQ_TAB_TABID.NEXTVAL, %s, TO_DATE(%s, 'DD-MM-YY'), %d)", escapeshellarg($name), escapeshellarg($dob), $_SESSION['usrid'])
```

In which case I get ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

and again when I run that query with SQL developer it works.

I know I am missing a minor thing here but this is my first time working with PHP and Oracle and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your user input is in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`, then why are you using the format `DD-MM-YY` to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the date with the right format:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(TABID, TABNAME, DOB, CREATEDBY)
    VALUES (SEQ_TAB_TABID.NEXTVAL, :1, TO_DATE(:2, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), :3)
```

Comment: Now I get ORA-01821: date format not recognized. and the date entered was 08/29/2015

Comment: @AbhinavMathur . . . This works in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c23a/1).  I am guessing that you might have other characters that are causing the problem.